# HOW to add histo in ROOT-framework?

Tags: histogram, root-framework

i choose to ask a question here well aware that i can infringe some rules of StackExchange maybe becouse this isn't the right place to ask that, but i saw a lot of question related to CERN ROOT. I know that here people that answer the questions prefer to show the way instead to give a cooked solution, but i need some help and i have no time to learn from the answers, i only want a solution for my problem. I apologize in advance!

Here is my problem: i have two .root files:

- one of a spectrum ("sezione_misura_90.root"),
- one from background ("sezione_fondo_90.root").

I have to subtract the second from the first and get a final histogram. Usually i open the file with the TBroswer and i have no idea how to implement a macro of a script to open a .root file or doing everything else, first of all becouse i hate ROOT and all programming related, and i have only a course where i am supposed to use that, without someone tell me how!!! Even the prof. don't know how to use...

If some one that read have a macro or a script ready to use, **I will be forever indebted to him** for sharing that with me. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
I write down a file named run.cxx with the following lines

int run()
{

```
// Open both files side-by-side
TFile* sezione_misura_90 = new TFile("sezione_misura_90.root");
TFile* sezione_fondo_90 = new TFile("sezione_fondo_90.root");

// Get the histograms from the file
// Since you didn't say from your post, I'm going to assume that
// the histograms are called "hist" and that they hold floating
// point values (meaning, they're TH1F histograms.  The "F" means float)

TH1F* h_misura = (TH1F*) sezione_misura_90->Get("hist");
TH1F* h_fondo = (TH1F*) sezione_fondo_90->Get("hist");

// Now we add them together
TH1F* h_sum = h_misura->Add(*h_fondo, -1);
```

}
There was some typos like ( and ;, i correct them but i get back the following.

Error: illegal pointer to class object h_misura 0x0 139  run.cxx:21:
**** Interpreter error recovered ****

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to accomplish this is to write a script that opens the two files, reads the histograms from the files, and subtracts them (which is the same as adding them using a factor of -1).  This can be done using a block of code similar to the following:

```
{

// Open both files side-by-side
TFile* sezione_misura_90 = new TFile("sezione_misura_90.root");
TFile* sezione_fondo_90 = new TFile(("sezione_fondo_90.root");

// Get the histograms from the file
// Since you didn't say from your post, I'm going to assume that
// the histograms are called "hist" and that they hold floating
// point values (meaning, they're TH1F histograms.  The "F" means float)

TH1F* h_misura = (TH1F*) sezione_misura_90->Get("hist");
TH1F* h_fondo = (TH1F*) sezione_fondo_90->Get("hist");

// Now we add them together
TH1F* h_sum = h_misura->Add(*h_fondo, -1);

}
```

At this point, h_sum should be the histogram you want.  You can save it to a file for later reading, or you can draw it to the screen if you're running an interactive root session.

The above code can be run by doing one of the following:

- An interactive root session just by typing root and then typing the above lines)
- As a root script (by pasting them into a file which, for example, could be named "file.C" and typing "root file.C")
- A larger program (by putting the above lines in a function and calling that function)

You can read more about the methods available for a Histogram in ROOT's documentation:
http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TH1.html#TH1:Add@1

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi. Really thx for the answer!! i tried to put in a file.C and execute but i get back this error:                                        Error: illegal pointer to class object h_misura 0x0 139  run.cxx:21:
*** Interpreter error recovered ***

Comment: Did you change the "hist" names in my code to match the histogram names in the files that you're reading from?

Comment: You'll need to know the names of the histograms in order to read and manipulate them.  You can do this by opening the root file. Just type "root fileName.root" and then type ".ls", which lists the contents of the file into the root prompt.

Comment: Thx to all, but i corrected the name with the right "ch2" but i get back an illegal pointer error. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two problems. One problem has to do with the way ROOT manages memory, more specifically ROOT objects in memory:

```
// Each ROOT object derives from a TNamed class, 
// hence has a <name>, which ROOT uses internally 
// to keep track of the objects
TH1F* h_misura = (TH1F*) sezione_misura_90->Get("hist");
// now you have a histogram named "hist" in memory; 
//btw, better to name it something more unique, e.g. hist1, at least
TH1F* h_fondo = (TH1F*) sezione_fondo_90->Get("hist");
// And now, you are trying to get another histogram named "hist",
// which creates a problem: Two different histograms with the same
// name - you can't do that.
// At the very least ROOT is going to overwrite the first hist 
// and replace it with the second, or bug out
```

Solution to problem one:

```
// Rename the "hist"s to something like "hist1" and "hist2"
TH1F* h_misura = (TH1F*) sezione_misura_90->Get("hist");
h_misura->SetName("hist1");
TH1F* h_fondo = (TH1F*) sezione_fondo_90->Get("hist");
h_fondo->SetName("hist2");
// now, you have to histograms in memory with unique names
```

Problem two: when you open a TFile with

```
// TFile * f = new TFile("file.root");
```

it opens it in a read-only mode, therefore you can't write to them if you want to save your sum of histograms. Instead do this:

```
TFile * f = TFile::Open("file.root", "write");
// and do a null pointer check
if (!f) { std::cout << "file not found" << std::endl; exit(1); }
// if you want to save the results to file f
// ...
f->cd();
hist->Write();
f->Close();
```